MapServer runtime substitution for ANGLE
I'm using MapServer CGI with Nginx and SpwanFCGI.
I need to use a "rotation" parameter coming from the WMS request and use it into one of my LAYERs' LABEL->ANGLE to align the label to the map rotation.
For a Database connection, it's pretty straight forward:
LAYER
    ...
    VALIDATION
        'rotation' '[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+'
    END
    ...
    # Here the WMS parameters is converted into an attribute...
    DATA "geom FROM (SELECT *, %rotation% as angle FROM ...) using unique table_id using srid=3857"
    ...
    CLASS
        LABEL
            # 'angle' is an attribute and can be used
            ANGLE [angle]
            ...
        END
    END

My problem is when I'm using a FlatGeoBuf file as data source: I have no fields where the runtime substitution works and where I can convert my parameter into an attribute.
Moreover the direct usage of "%rotation%" seems to work only as string.under
I tried may options and even with EXPRESSION and a less precise approach like
    LABEL
        EXPRESSION (%rotation% > 0 and %rotation%  <= 20)
        ANGLE 10
    END
    ...
    LABEL
        EXPRESSION (%rotation% > 20 and %rotation%  < 40)
        ANGLE 30
    END

But MapServer generates an error in "msEvalExpression".
Do you know any workaround to use a WMS request parameter as an attribute?
Thanks.
